# jquery UI add a second close anchor on modal dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to add a second close button to my my UI modal box in addition to the close window text to the top right of my modal box.

How can I do this?

here is my code so far

```
    function showDialog(){
    $("#example").dialog({
        modal: true // Make the dialog "modal" (show an overlay beneath the dialog)
    });
    return false;   
}
```

Here is the url for the modal, if you click show dialog t show the modal box
http://satbulsara.com/NSJ-LOCAL-02-06/eqs1.htm

Thanks,

Sat

Comment: Please can you describe what you mean by "multiple close anchor tag" -- do you mean you want more than one close button on a dialog form, in addition to the default upper right hand corner close button/link? If so where is it to be placed?

Comment: what you mean ??? add another close anchor tag ?? clarify your question ....?

Comment: Hi There, sorry about that that. I would like to add another close button. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#second-anchor-id").click(function(){
   $("#example").dialog("close");
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi there, how would I create the second close button to my modal? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
function showDialog(){
    $("#example").dialog({
        modal: true // Make the dialog "modal" (show an overlay beneath the dialog)
        buttons:{ "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
    });
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: Hi there, i have added the close button locally to the bottom of my modal box but would like second close window option that is wrapped in an anchor tag. How can I achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Please show us your html and tell us exactly what you want to achieve so that we could better help you.

Comment: Hi Raja I have added a url to my question. Thanks